# Sort a multi dimensional array based on 3 columns

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am at the beginning to learn... I have a array like this:

```
"12", "FC Bayern München", "98", "80", "91"
"34", "Bayer 04 Leverkusen", "65", "26", "65"
"23", "Borussia Dortmund", "81", "39", "66"
```

TeamID, TeamName, GoalsScore, GoalsDif, Points

Now I want to sort the array by:

```
first: Point, second: GoalsDif, third: GoalsScore
```

How can I sort it?

Comment: Create a wrapper class and use comparator.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: I know about comparator, but I need a little help to start with it...

Comment: http://www.javatpoint.com/Comparator-interface-in-collection-framework  it may be helpful for you

Answer (score 2):

Create a wrapper class which will represent team's statistics. That class should have fields you mentioned:
TeamID, TeamName, GoalsScore, GoalsDif, Points

Then you can compare those objects using [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface and sort by whatever you want.

Comment: Or you could make the class [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and sort on it (and use it as a key) in lots of places without having to use a Comparator.  You probably don't want it here, but it's an option to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://techthinking.net/2010/04/how-to-sort-two-dimensional-data-based-on-multiple-parameters/).

In above example, MVC architecture is used but you can re-use the code of sorting by multiple columns using `Comparator`.

I hope it will be helpful !